# What is the value of an report parameter which allows multiple value, no null vals & gets its value from a query when you don't check any checkbox?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I got an ssrs report which has a parameter @param which is configured to allows multiple value, no null values and gets its value from a query.

I want to be able to test the rdl's sql query by putting the report's parameter value in a declared variable in sql server

```
declare @param type = value
```

The question is what is the type and value of this variable when you don't tick any checkbox in the actual report.

Comment: It's `nothing` and if your parameter f it's setup like that your report should not be able to run anyway. If you want to test the query with a value that WILL be passed then it depends on what type you set in the parameter and/or what the data type is for the value field that you chose when you set the available values query.

Comment: How do I represent nothing in a variable form in sql server

Comment: because in my where statement I have "where fieldname in (@param)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't choose a value from your list, your report will not run so how can you test it?

Your parameter is based on a query, the `Value` field you chose when you set the parameter up will be value or values passed to the query with the same datatype, so if you pass a list of integers then SSRS will pass integers to your query

**.. however...**

Let's say you had a list of items with ID's that you use as your parmeters values and it looks like this

```
myID  myDescription
1     Apples
2     Oranges
3     Pears
4     Carrots
5     Onions
```

and your user chose 'Apples' and 'Pears', then 1 and 3 would be passed to the query.

If your dataset query is something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myID IN (@myParameter)
```

and , assuming your query is directly in your dataset (and not a stored proc) then SSRS will automatically convert the passed in values to a comma delimited list so the query executed will look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myID IN (1, 3)
```

What this means is that you can only really test the query with a single value unless you hardcode your test values in place of the `@myParameter`

*Note: You should not declare @myParameter in your dataset query.*